# Laravel Eloquent Multiple Joins Type Conversion

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, pdo

When I do a query like this with multiple joins and retrieve a single column on the nested join, in that example `h.mv` ,it looses it's type information in laravel and gets treated as a string whereas the column in the mysql database is a DECIMAL.

```
Account::select('accounts.*', 'accounts.id', 'h.mv', 'h.mv_local')
            ->with('currency')
            ->join('sem', 'sem.entity_id', '=', 'accounts.id')
            ->join('s', 's.id', '=', 'sem.security_id')
            ->join('h', 'h.security_id', '=', 's.id') 
            ->join('st', 'st.id', '=', 's.type1_id')
            ->join('hA', 'hA.id', '=', 'h.entity_id')
            ->where('st.name', '!=', 'CA') //
            ->where('h.date', $this->T)
            ->whereIn('accounts.type', ['pa', 'f'])
            ->where('hA.type', '!=', 'subMandate')
            ->whereRaw('`hA`.`asset_id` = `accounts`.`asset_id`')
            ->when($this->mandate_ids, function ($query) {
                return $query->whereIn('accounts.id', $this->custodial_ids);
            })
            ->get();
```

Is that expected behaviour when dealing with multiple joins? I can find old articles stating that the pdo bridge will treat every column as a string and laravel is doing the type conversion so I'm wondering what the constraints are on type conversion or even if that is actually what's happening?

Any experts on eloquent or the pdo layer who could give me some advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you read this [issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/23850)? I don't think that join method itself loose type, problem lies deeper. Moreover, you didn't show your mapping/schema of the table in php, version of framework, database engine and version etc. etc. and etc. ) I think this answer in the [issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/23850#issuecomment-380479255) could solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks @SergeyLigus this explains it well